# Page in linear iCarousel shifts up while scrolling it horizontally?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiscrollview, icarousel

I am using iCarousel of Linear type to implement paging. Each page can scroll vertically in its place. The problem is when i start scrolling horizonatlly the page shifts up to the top. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: pls provide ur code ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to increase the **view** size in the **delegate**

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

or else the **spacing** in **delegate**

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)_carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value
```